# Android Streetview check Availability

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view

I'm using Android Google Maps V2 and currently working on Google StreetView. I want to know if a certain location has streetview available before going to the Streetview Activity which has the StreetViewPanoramaFragment.

```
@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
    gMapStreetView = streetViewPanorama;
    gMapStreetView.setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener(new StreetViewPanorama.OnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStreetViewPanoramaChange(StreetViewPanoramaLocation streetViewPanoramaLocation) {
            if (streetViewPanoramaLocation != null && streetViewPanoramaLocation.links != null) {
                // has street view
            } else {
                // no street view
            }
        }
    });

    loadMap();
}
```

I already use the above code but this code is can be use only when you have StreetViewPanoramaFragment, which is already in my StreetView Activity.

Any suggestion like there is a function like to get location or links

```
streetview.getLocation();
        // or
streetview.getLinks();
```

To check first if there is a streetview on a specific longitude and latitude.

Thank you

Comment: check this SO question [3865607](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865607/how-to-tell-if-a-streetview-exists-before-launching-streetview-intent) and [17218672](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218672/how-to-check-if-position-if-valid-in-streetview-in-android) if it can help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of KENdi, this link help me to solve the problem in ratana's suggestion

[How to check if position if valid in StreetView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218672/how-to-check-if-position-if-valid-in-streetview-in-android)